# A feature ranking algorithm

Tags: algorithm

if I have the following partitions or subsets  with the corresponding scores as follows:

- {X1,X2}  with score C1
- {X2,X3}  with score C2
- {X3,X4}  with score C3
- {X4,X1}  with score C4

I want to write an algorithm that will rank the Xs based on the corresponding score of the subset they appeared in.

one way for example will be to  do the following:

- X1 = (C1 + C4)/2
- X2 = (C1 + C2)/2
- X3 = (C2 + C3)/2
- X4 = (C3 + C4)/2

and then sort the results.

is there a more efficient or better ideas to  do the ranking?

Comment: Does each X only appear twice? Or are you expecting more.

Comment: The subsets or the partitions will contain randomly chosen items.You can think of it that I have chosen these random items or features and calculated some score and I want to find a way to rank these items or features. The number of fetters in each subset or partition will be the same.

Comment: Your example is very specific, are you expecting examples like this one ?? Partitions of 2 sets ( going on cercle ) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you think that the score of a set is the sum of the scores of each object, you can write your equation in matrix form as :

```
C = M * X
```

where C is a vector of length 4 with components C1, C2, C3, C4, M is the matrix (in your case, as I understand this may vary)

```
1 1 0 0
0 1 1 0
0 0 1 1
1 0 0 1
```

and X is the unknown. You can then use Gaussian elimination to determine X and the get the ranking as you suggested.

Comment: Thank you. if I want to get more ideas , in which algorithms area I should search in ?

Comment: It really depends on the kind of problems you will be looking at. Do you expect that there will always be as many inputs as outputs ? Do you know if this linear relation (value of {X1,X2} = value of X1+value of X2) is valid ? If not, do you have a hint of what the correct relationship should be or are there examples when you now both the vectors C and X ?

Comment: so we are we solving for equations of the form

Comment: so we are we solving for equations of the form "X1 + X2= C1" as for the first line of the matrix ?. the relation between the features and the Cs is not yet known and I am trying to find the best approximation.